# let jsp file go to servlet

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets

I've got a problem with my .jsp file after it does something it must go to my login.java (servlet) I thought this was possible by doing:

login.java servlet in the web-inf/ serverlet folder ( that i created )
and in my jsp page doing this ${pageContext.request.contextPath}/servlets/login as url.

The problem then is that I get an error "The requested resource () is not available." with code 404.

Is it not possible to let a jsp go to an servlet via url?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the servlet as a normal Java class in a package in the Java source code folder, not in a manually created folder in the web folder. You also need to map the servlet on an URL pattern.

Create a package `com.example` (or something else, but it *must* be in a package) in the Java source code folder and then create the following class the usual Java way:

```
package com.example;

// ...

@WebServlet("/login")
public class Login extends HttpServlet {

    // ...

}
```

If you're using an IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans, then it will be automatically compiled into the right folder and after deployment it will be available on the URL `/login`, relative to the context path.

```html
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login" method="post">
```

If you're still not using a Servlet 3.0 compatible container (Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, etc), then you need to remove the `@WebServlet` annotation and register the servlet the old fashioned way in `web.xml` as follows:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.Login</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

#### See also:

- [Our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - contains some Hello World examples

Comment: Thanks, only the webservlet doesn't work gives me error, searchd on google and I needed to include import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet; but that doens't exist in spring source tool suite. the webservlet gives me the attribute value is undefined for the annotation type webservlet. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Then remove it and use the old fashioned `web.xml` configuration approach as shown in the linked wiki page. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Only there is still something wrong and I double checked everything of typos: http://pastebin.com/iwZxBhgh

Comment: Is "be.uhasselt.burgerdemocratie" the full qualified class name? It seems to be the sole package name. If it's indeed the FQN despite of violating the Java Naming Conventions, then this error means that it's not been compiled into the right place. What IDE are you using?

Comment: I did exactly the same as in the tutorial also just give the package name here are 2 screenshots of my web.xml and my servlet. I'm using spring tool suite. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/608219/1.png http://dl.dropbox.com/u/608219/2.png thanks for your help.

Comment: I added the .RegisterControl to the package and then it doesn't give errors any more but then it just shows the localhost:8080 default page when I go to regControl so I don't think my servlet is active.

Comment: Your servlet is sending a redirect to that URL when there's no session, so it's working perfectly fine. Run a debugger or add poor man's `System.out.println()` calls, you'll see that it's been invoked. I have by the way the impression that you haven't really read the linked servlets wiki page. I warmly recommend you to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put .java files into your compiled application. Check this tutorial: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/page-views-controller.html for example of jsp+servlet developing with NetbeansIDE.
And answer of the question: yes, it is entirely possible.

Comment: No the are compiled and deployed on the tomcat server, but my jsp page doesn't find the /servlet/login . I have a controller everything. That tutorial I already read that.